# Upload Progress Bar for file upload

Tags: vb.net

i have this code, how do i incorporate a progress bar into it?

```
 Private Sub btn_upload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_upload.Click

    Dim filePath As String = lbl_file.Text
    Dim slashPosition As Integer = filePath.LastIndexOf("\")
    Dim filenameOnly As String = filePath.Substring(slashPosition + 1)


    Dim request As System.Net.FtpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create("ftp://.com/public_html/windows/" & filenameOnly), System.Net.FtpWebRequest)
    request.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("", "")
    request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile
    Dim path As String = lbl_file.Text

    Dim file() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path)

    Dim strz As System.IO.Stream = request.GetRequestStream()

    strz.Write(file, 0, file.Length)


    strz.Close()
    strz.Dispose()

    MsgBox(path)




End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of reading all the bytes at once and then uploading them all at once, you could read and write the bytes in chunks of a set size and then calculate the percentage based on the total bytes.  As a quick example, here's how you could update the progress of the upload each kilobyte sent.

```
For offset as Integer = 0 to File.Length Step 1024
    ProgressBar1.Value = CType(offset * ProgressBar1.Maximum / File.Length, Integer)
    Dim chunkSize as Integer = File.Length - offset - 1
    If chunkSize > 1024 Then chunkSize = 1024
    strz.Write(file, offset, chunkSize)
Next
ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum
```

Comment: Ah works now, how would i go about getting this to update periodically into a progress bar that i have on my form? Cheers for all the help!!!

Comment: @HarryBeasant I changed the label in the example to a ProgressBar control.  If this answers your question, do you mind accepting it as the answer?

Comment: @HarryBeasant - use a BackgroundWorker to show realtime status on a progressbar